# Modify select element using CSS

Tags: html, css, listbox

I'm trying to "cheat" the design of a select box to act as an inline tab/widget.

After done some research, I know it's hard to modify by CSS. But I think it's probably manageable.

So, based on the snippet, when I click the option, the text will turn white. Only once I click some white space, the text become black. Why is that and how to fix it?

Secondly, how to remove the right side arrow bar thing? I run this CSS on the staging site, chrome doesn't show the arrow bar, but mozilla got.

```css
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background-image: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #868686;
}

select option {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 128px;
}

select option:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

select option:checked {
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  /* for IE */
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option value="">Latest</option>
  <option value="52">New</option>
  <option value="53">Pre-Owned</option>
  <option value="115">Unworn</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to use this simple way.

please remove this css

```
background: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
background-color: #ffffff !important;
```

from `select option:checked`

Or need to hide scroll then you can add `overflow: auto;` into `select`

Let me know further clarification

```css
  select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background-image: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #868686;
      overflow: auto;
}

select option {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 128px;
}

select option:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

select option:checked {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 600;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option value="">Latest</option>
  <option value="52">New</option>
  <option value="53">Pre-Owned</option>
  <option value="115">Unworn</option>
</select>
```

Comment: although the bar is no longer display now, but the active text is not in black. I want it to be black with white background.